# How to protect content data with login with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to protect some web page (html/php file) with username and password, so with a login phase. 
So I have created this private.php file:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include 'MyLibrary.php';

$object = new Manager ( $conn );
if ($object->checkPassword ( $_POST ['username'], $_POST ['password'] )) {
    $_SESSION ["logged"] = $_POST ["username"];

} else {
}

if (isset ( $_SESSION ["logged"] )) { // the user is logged
    echo session_id ();
} else {
    echo "Wrong";
    header ( 'location: /login.php' );
    exit ();
}
function check_logged() {
    if (isset ( $_SESSION ["logged"] )) { // the user is logged
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

This file contains a Manager class, which can deal with MySQL DB and has the method checkPassword, which return true if both username and password are corrects.

This is the page need to be protect, which I called Client.php:

```
    <?php
session_start ();
include 'private.php';


    if (if (isset ( $_POST ['var1'] ) && isset ( $_POST ['var2'] )) {) {
//the work to be done with var1 && var2 must secure
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use Java software to send var1 and var2 in post; at first I send username and password to private.php and later to Client.php with var1 and var2, but I got null as response. If I don't send any post information, I got the error string about the fact I don't send any post data. So my questions are:

1. How Can I do to solve the problem with post ?
2. How Can I protect the content in the case of username and password not correct ? I want to display an error message like: Not authorized.